# Why javax.faces.ViewState input is created when all beans are request scoped

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, viewstate, stateless

Is this possible to prevent both client-side ViewState hidden input and server-side in-memory view-per-session? I have a *state-less* website built on JSF 2.2 and all my beans are stateless. They are either request or singleton beans.